# How to get a head to track an empty

Tags: modifiers, rigging

I've been working on this robot character and I'm trying to animate so that all the body parts float, similar to that of rayman.

The problem I'm having is I can't get the floating head to track an empty, it comes up with a red box when i try.

How can I rig up this figure properly and get it to move around like it is floating?

Blend file here for reference:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/h0gc9837wnutcoc/AACIO3YAgyFSY7MviS15yyI1a?dl=0

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

Add the empty to your scene and position it in front of the head, then select your head object and apply rotation by pressing CTRL+A and select "rotation" from the list:
[image]

Now with your head still selected, go to the constraints panel and add a "Track To" constraint, and in the Target field select the Empty you want the head to follow:
[image]

Note: You may have to change the axis in the Track To constraint, depending on which way your head is looking. Judging by your screenshot, I suspect it will be something like -Y

Comment: Just tried this out and it worked, thank you so much for your help

Comment: no problem. rock on :D